# UISearchController only update on search button click

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchController which is configured to search a very large array of data. As such, when I am typing in the search bar, it takes a very long time to actually type out my search. It performs the search comparison with every character entry in the search field, which is very slow.

I am wondering how to fix this. My thoughts are:

1. only perform the search after the user finishes typing and hits the search button
2. perform the search on a background thread, freeing up the main thread for keyboard entry

**I would like to use method 1**
but I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the new UISearchController.

Below is my relevant project code:

```
class AirportSearchTBVC: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating{
var airportData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var filteredData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var searchController = UISearchController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    definesPresentationContext = true


    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    filteredData = []

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (airportData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    filteredData = array as! [Dictionary<String, String>]

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

**Bonus question**
If I search for a string, it doesn't appear to be returning any results if the string doesn't match perfectly. For example: "orida" does not find "Florida". Isn't my search predicate supposed to find this using CONTAINS?

**Update**
This code nearly works, but it basically throws a bunch of stuff on the background thread and then chugs through it. The keyboard is lively now, but it seems to crash if I change things in the text field quickly on it while dismissing and re-entering the search bar...

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    appDel.backgroundThread(background: {
        self.filteredData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (self.airportData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

        self.filteredData = array as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
        },
        completion: {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

    });






}
```

**Update 2**
After playing a bit with it, I was able to get it to work pretty decently by both waiting for a searchBar.text length >= 3 characters as well as making sure the character count didn't change within 1 second of the updateSearchResultsForSearchController: being called. The combination of these as well as integrating a search button execute command should resolve my problem.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let startCount = searchController.searchBar.text!.length
    delay(1) {
    if searchController.searchBar.text!.length >= 3 && searchController.searchBar.text!.length == startCount{
        self.view.addSubview(self.progressHud)
        self.appDel.backgroundThread(background: {
            self.filteredData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
            let array = (self.airportData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

            self.filteredData = array as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
            },
            completion: {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.progressHud.removeFromSuperview()
                }



        });
    }
    }





}
    func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the delegate method `searchBarSearchButtonPressed:` to monitor when the search button is pressed. Set a flag when this delegate method is executed and then in your `searchBarTextDidChange:` method you can check this flag to see if you should execute the search. Of course this will only search after the user presses search, and most people expect to see something happening while they're typing.

Comment: Is there another tactic you'd recommend? Considering people expect to see something different?

Comment: Well you could put your entire `searchBarTextDidChange:` execution in a background thread with GCD, and then before you update the `tableView` you can hop back to the main thread to ensure that the UI updates quickly.

Comment: I have updated my question with code that tries to do what you've recommended, but it is essentially bugging out because it is putting many requests in the background thread and then "chugs" through each one... I really appreciate your help here :)

Comment: You could try to start searching after only a certain number of characters are entered (like 3?) which would cut down on your requests

Comment: Ok - I'll play with that and see if that helps. Appreciate your help! I'll accept this answer and keep posting updates as I get closer.

Comment: the correct delegate method you suggest is which is located in UISearchBarDelegate 
```
//    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
//    optional func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when keyboard search button pressed
```

Answer (score 11):

If you would like to only perform the search when the user clicks the "Search" button - which seems both sensible and reasonable for a larger and slower access data set, you can do it like this:

```
class AirportSearchTBVC: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating{
var airportData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var filteredData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var searchController = UISearchController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    definesPresentationContext = true


    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    filteredData = []

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (airportData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    filteredData = array as! [Dictionary<String, String>]

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

}
```

The key differences are to set the searchController.searchBar.delegate = self, and to put your search code in the searchBarSearchButtonClicked function instead of the updateSearchResultsForSearchController - which should now do nothing.
I apologise for any errors, I tested this code using Xcode v7.0.1 Objective-C, and then transposed the changes.

Comment: Appreciate your effort in this answer, but I actually wanted the search to be performed after update or upon search button press. This could easily help someone else having similar issues though. Thanks!

Comment: The signature for the method is: 'func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)' (as of now). Using the signature with the argument label will do nothing

Answer (score 0):

@pbush25

the correct name for **the method** you suggested which is located in **UISearchBarDelegate** as per documentation is

```
//    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
//    optional func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when keyboard search button pressed
```